# Firebase Functions and Puppeteer - TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

When I run this function on my local machine in the Firebase Emulator it works great, but when I deploy it to the cloud I get a lot of:

> TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Code is very simple:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

exports.myFunc = functions
.runWith({ memory: '2GB' })
.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://example.com", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    const pageContent = await page.content();

    await browser.close();

    response.send(pageContent);

});
```

I get a lot of this in the Firebase Functions log:

[image]

You can see this in the Google Cloud report too:
[image]

Why are so many runs getting timeout?

Comment: The fact that it is exactly 30 seconds makes me feel like either it is timing out, or the container is not detecting when your code is done. But I'm not sure why it's 30 seconds, as I thought the default time-out was much longer than that.

Comment: Puppeteer default timeout is 30 seconds. If I put a try / catch around this line it catches the timeout: await page.goto("https://example.com", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

Comment: You should be able to change the timeout with https://pptr.dev/next/api/puppeteer.page.setdefaulttimeout